# Classes is not in the build unless they are instantiated

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm writing a small library for some simple components to learn some `TypeScript` but there is a problem building the library when not explicitly instantiating the class.

I want to be able to, using a string, to instantiate a class. Right after defining a class I add the class name and constructor to an object.

```
/**
 * Component class store
 */
let classes: { [key: string]: IConstructable<IComponent> } = {};

export function addToDynamic(cls: IConstructable<IComponent>) {
    classes[cls.name] = cls;
}

/**
 * A component
 */
export class Container extends BaseComponent implements IComponent {
    items: object[];

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

addToDynamic(Container);
```

The following code does not work because `Container` is not instantiated:

```
import { Container } from './gui/container';
import { DynamicClass } from './gui/base';

let c2:Container = new DynamicClass('Container') as Container;
c2.add(document.body);
```

This will however include `Container` in the build:

```
import { Container } from './gui/container';
import { DynamicClass } from './gui/base';

let c1:Container = new Container();
let c2:Container = new DynamicClass('Container') as Container;
c2.add(document.body);
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'sugar-ant-lib',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    }
};
```

The question is how to include all files in `src`?

**Update**

Adding the line below to my `index.ts` adds the file to the build.

```
import './gui/container';
```

Also I've figured out that it might have something to do with [tripple-slash directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) but I don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is creating the dependency graph by identifying the **import or require** keyword from your files recursively. If any files which doesn't import anywhere on your project , webpack couldn't find it. This will give an advantage by removing unused files in the build

One solution is add the import statement explicitly on any files , So web pack will add that also in to the dependency graph.

Another solution would be dynamic import , dynamically import the file on your code where it best fit , the file name will be dynamic. So web pack will create an module based on the name.

https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234

More about dependency graph

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/dependency-graph/